# How to add a reusable workflow to the SharePoint Library using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, pnp-powershell, sharepoint-library, reusable-workflow

I have to add Reusable workflow(2013) to SharePoint library through PowerShell.
I am trying to automate this in one of my project.
OR Is there any possibilities we can achieve this? 
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If the workflow is saved as a template, then you can use PowerShell script for adding a solution and activate it.

1Add a solution:

```
Add-SPUserSolution -LiteralPath <LiteralPath> -Site <SiteURL>
```

2.Install a solution:

```
Install-SPUserSolution -Identity <Solution> -Site <SiteURL>
```

3.Activate a solution:

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity <Feature> -Url <URL>
```